# Prestashop get access to cart variables in the custom module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In prestashop I want to get the exact payment details step data in my payment module. So I just made copy the code from order-payment.tpl and used that in my payment execution smarty file. It showed couple of errors. So I just go through the codes and get those values from the cart and made it assign from my payment controller to the smarty template. Everything works fine but still I am getting one error named as

```
Undefined index: gift_products .
```

When I checked the code in Cart.php I got it like this

```
$gift_products = array();
$gift_product = $product;
$gift_product['cart_quantity'] = 1;
$gift_product['price'] = 0;
$gift_product['price_wt'] = 0;
$gift_product['total_wt'] = 0;
$gift_product['total'] = 0;
$gift_product['gift'] = true;
$gift_products[] = $gift_product;

I tried to assign the value of gift_products to the smarty like this

public function initContent()
{
    parent::initContent();

    $cart = $this->context->cart;
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'gift_products' => $cart->gift_products,
    ));

    $this->setTemplate('payment_execution.tpl');
}
```

But its not working at all. Can someone tell me how to use the variable/array of cart in my module? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
$summary = $this->context->cart->getSummaryDetails();
$gift_products = $summary['gift_products'];
```